# How much Scala should I know to be good in gatling tool?

Tags: gatling

How much Scala language should I know to be good at gatling tool? Please help me. If any one tried integration with Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

for straightforward simulations where you just make requests, get parts of the response and then use those in subsequent requests you don't scala at any level of depth. It can help from the perspective of code reuse etc though.

If you've got a more complicated scenario, familiarity with scala collections will help. In my app I have the requirement to combine and filter lists of values returned by api requests before forwarding to a subsequent request - this required a bit of scala to get working.